# Operate local development server without internet access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I am running a `puma` local server for a Ruby on Rails app using Chrome and the `better_errors` gem.  If my internet is disconnected, I can still work with the development server but if I hit an exception caused by a `raise`, then I get the following error:

```
getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

and the browser does not load `better_errors`. It appears that the exception is executing code that requires access to the internet. How do I overcome this problem, so I can use my local server without internet access.

Comment: Do you have `config.consider_all_requests_local = true` set in `development.rb`?

Comment: Yes I do have it set to true.